# struggling with correct way to name this method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Long time c#/java/c++ programmer, brand spankin new to objectivce C.  Read the guidelines, looked api's, but not quite there yet on the naming convention.

Example: assume I have a Cars class that has an array of every car, and you wanted methods to return a subset of the array.

I see NSArray has a method: getObjects, but in most cases I don't see the "get".  So 
what do you prefer?

**All inputs appreciated!**  Spent way too much time thinking about this.

Option A)  -(NSArray *) getCarsWithColor:(NSString *)color;

Option B)  -(NSArray *) getCars:(NSString *)withColor;

Optoin C)  -(NSArray *) carsWithColor:(NSString *)color;

OPtion D)  -(NSArray *) cars:(NSString *)withColor;

Option E)  none of the above, name it xxxxxxxxxxxx....

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Objective-C methods are seldom named with `get`. The `getObjects:` method has `get` in it only because the result is placed in a buffer in an input argument.

```
-(void)getObjects:(id*)aBuffer;
  ^^^^                 ^^^^^^^
```

whereas your method is not filling a buffer, but return an array. Option (A) and (B) are out.

Also, the kind of argument is usually part of the selector name (stuff before `:`), e.g.

```
-(UIView*)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag
              ^^^^^^^
// not view:(NSInteger)withTag

-(CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromView:(UIView *)view
// not convert:(CGPoint)point from:(UIView*)view;
```

so option (D) is discouraged.

A detailed guideline for naming methods can be found in [*Coding Guidelines for Cocoa: Naming Methods*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html). This guideline also include other conventions which you may be interested.

Answer (score 1):

Option C is the best. Never use "get" unless you're getting pointers into a C array and the arguments should only be named for the method signature that refers to them.

This way, longer methods with multiple arguments are clearer:

```
-(NSArray *)carsWithColor:(NSColor *)color 
                   wheels:(NSInteger)wheels 
                    seats:(NSInteger)seats 
          premiumInterior:(BOOL)premiumInterior ...
```

...which can be shortened to: `-carsWithColor:wheels:seats:premiumInterior:...` when describing it to others.

Answer (score 1):

"C" is the standard way to do it. `get` is very rarely used in getters and the more verbose `carsWithColor` is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what everyone else has said, I'd be curious why you're storing an NSArray of objects in the Cars class. It sounds to me like cars is an NS[Mutable]Array ivar somewhere containing instances of the car class. Then, you don't need this method at all. If you're using Core Data, then you'd do a fetch and if you're just handling the NSArray yourself, you could use a predicate to filter the array's objects. I think that is the bit that strikes me as the most un-Cocoa aspect of your question. If you do need this method, then it would be defined on the object containing the NSArray ivar like:

```
NSArray *cars = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:car1, car2, car3, nil];
(NSArray *)carsWithColor:(NSString *)color{
    return [cars filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"color == %@", color]];
}
```

That code is untested, but it's how I would approach the problem. The method is really a controller type method and shouldn't be part of your model logic. Having the Cars class sounds like muddled MVC to me.

Comment: +1 this is a great point.  Why does the class itself keep track of the instances?

Comment: Thanks for the input on predicates. I"m a big fan of extension methods in c#, and predicates appear to provide the same functionality. My example on cars was made up on the fly to demonstrate my confusion on how to name methods.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C method names do not use the `get` prefix. So option C is closest to being correct, with the caveat that the `aWithB` construction implies the `NSArray *` that comes back will be `autorelease`-d.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, there are so many ways to do what you're trying to do!  Usually, the "get..." notation should be avoided unless you're defining a custom getter, to avoid confusion.  I vote for option C, "-(NSArray *) carsWithColor:(NSString *)color;".